# RecyclerView LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL можно ли останавливать экран?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

RecyclerView LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL можно ли сделать так, чтобы при горизантальном прокручивание экран останавливался или фиксировался?

Не останавливался на середине между экранами, а именно фиксировался на самом тексте или изображении

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте ViewPager для этого

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39036351/3212712) вам нужен [LinearSnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearSnapHelper.html), который надо использовать так:

```
SnapHelper helper = LinearSnapHelper();
helper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

---

По первой ссылке есть и другие решения

Comment: Я Вас понял. Спасибо, сейчас попробую разобраться